# I am getting error when i call function def because_you_watched error is sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

```
import random

def because_you_watched(user, user_item, users, movies, k=5, N=5):

    movieTableIDs = get_rated_movies_ids(user, user_item, users, movies)
    df = get_movies(movieTableIDs, movies_table)

    movieIDs = random.sample(list([df.movieId, N]))

    for movieID in movieIDs:
        title = df[df.movieId == movieID].iloc[0].title
        print("Because you've watched ", title)
        similar_and_display(movieID, movies_table, movies, k)


because_you_watched(500, user_item, users, movies, k=5, N=5)
```

Comment: is the intention of you code correct ?

Comment: yes it is @seralouk

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: it works @seralouk

Comment: thank you @seralouk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is stated in Pawel's answer. The sample function of the random package takes two arguments and you only supply one as a list. Assuming the `N` parameter means number of samples you could try something like `movieIDs = random.sample(list(df.movieId),N)`. Otherwise, why not just use the sample method of pandas' dataframe [documented here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html).

> DataFrame.sample(n=None, frac=None, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=None, axis=None)
>
> Return a random sample of items from an axis of object.
>
> n : int, optional
>
> Number of items from axis to return. Cannot be used with frac. Default = 1 if frac = None.

Then you can just do `sample = list(df.sample(n=N).movieId)` I think.

Answer (score 0):

### You are missing the second argument in `random.sample` function.

According to the documentation:

> random.sample(population, k)
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements
>   chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without
>   replacement.

**Replace this:**

```
movieIDs = random.sample(list([df.movieId, N]))
```

**with this**

```
movieIDs = random.sample(list(df.movieId), N)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a value of k in this line of code:

```
movieIDs = random.sample(list([df.movieId, N]))
```

as random.sample takes two arguments specified in [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)